# Live Agent Chat - Routing by Region

Tags: liveagent, service-cloud-console, einstein, chat, snap-ins

I'm trying to figure out the best solution here and haven't had much luck from what I can find online or from talking with Salesforce.

We're using Live Agent embedded on our company website as our chat tool. When an agent is online, an end user interacts with an Einstein Bot. After interacting with the bot, they're transferred to an agent.

What we want to do is have it so if someone in the US interacts with Live Agent on our website, talks with the einstein bot, and then gets transferred to an online agent, then the chat is routed to a US agent rather than an agent who is also online, but in EMEA.

What would be the best way to accomplish this? We use Clearbit to collect the IP address and convert that to a region but how would that even get passed into a chat and then get used by Einstein or Live Agent to determine how the chat gets routed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the snap-in tag on your post, I'm going to assume you're using a custom snap-in with the Live Chat APi instead of your own custom JS to connect to the Console from your web site. How you send the info can provide you with some options. You also have the option (I'd assume you would be) to use separate agent queues for EMEA and North America.

A client I work with also obtains IP Adresses which they store in cookies. They use their own JS to send chats to the Lightning Console (no bots involved, but there's also other integration).

How to do this would depend on where you're doing the computations for where the customer is located. If you know at the time when they're interacting with the bot, I see no reason why you can't add a hidden field to the LiveAgent pre-chat form that gets sent to Omni-Channel. In your case, it could essentially be a Boolean that points to either NorthAmerica or EMEA for routing purposes. You'd then configure that as part of your routing rules for the chat.

Otherwise, you'd need to have your component or a sub-component pre-process your form using JS to determine which Region to route to before submitting the chat to Omni-Channel.